# python-social-auth: AttributeError at /complete/google-oauth2/: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'provider'

Tags: django, python-2.7, google-oauth, python-social-auth

I am using my corporate account (which is "Google for works" account) to implement Google oauth2.0 login in to my django application.

Pipeline in "settings.py" looks like:

```
SOCIAL_AUTH_PIPELINE = [
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.social_details',
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.social_uid',
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.auth_allowed',
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.associate_by_email',
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.associate_user',
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.load_extra_data',
    'social.pipeline.user.user_details',
]
```

Adding conditional backends to pipepline.

```
if config.GCPAuthentication.AUTO_CREATE_ACCOUNTS:
    SOCIAL_AUTH_PIPELINE.extend([
    'social.pipeline.user.get_username',
    'social.pipeline.user.create_user'
])
```

While trying to login for the very first time with a new user, I am getting error: 
AttributeError at /complete/google-oauth2/: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'provider'

And interestingly, user is getting created and saved in DB and on next login attempt it allows me to login.

Its throwing error here : https://github.com/omab/python-social-auth/blob/master/social/actions.py#L70

My corporate Google account might not have any social account(Google+ is disabled)/related info associated with it. Is that an issue?

In any case, can you please tell me any workaround to get rid of this issue?

Comment: what do get_username() and create_user() return?

Comment: How can I check that?
In the users, the new user getting created with username as my email ID, this is because i have,
    SOCIAL_AUTH_USERNAME_IS_FULL_EMAIL = True in settings.py

Comment: I changed the sequence of functions pipeline and it worked:
I guess it should follow the way it is mentioned here: https://github.com/omab/python-social-auth/blob/master/docs/pipeline.rst

Thanks @luke_aus.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The pipeline expects to follow the order in which functions needs to be called.
To my solution right sequence should be like:

```
SOCIAL_AUTH_PIPELINE = [  # Note: Sequence of functions matters here.
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.social_details',  # 0
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.social_uid',  # 1
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.auth_allowed',  # 2
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.social_user',  # 3
    'social.pipeline.user.get_username',  # 4
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.associate_by_email',  # 5
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.associate_user',  # 6
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.load_extra_data',  # 7
    'social.pipeline.user.user_details',  # 8
]

# Adding conditional functions to pipepline.
# NOTE: Sequence of functions matters here.
if config.GCPAuthentication.AUTO_CREATE_ACCOUNTS:
    SOCIAL_AUTH_PIPELINE.insert(6, 'social.pipeline.user.create_user')
```

Comment: I am facing similar problem. My pipeline order is same as above and have added a custom pipeline 'create_user_account' after 'user_details'. Both 'request' and 'user' are absent in the 'request' object passed to this pipeline. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38973264/on-upgrading-python-social-auth-from-0-1-17-to-0-2-4-session-attribute-is-not-p

Comment: This may be because user_details function doesn't pass anything to next function in pipeline. As per your requirement you might need to change the order of functions in your pipeline:
https://github.com/omab/python-social-auth/blob/master/social/pipeline/user.py#L75

Answer (score 1):

Yes you are right, Sequence of the function in the pipeline matters here as return of one function will be input to the next function in pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

As a sidenote I want to add that I faced a similar issue when I updated my `USER` model by changing it's primary key. In such scenarios, simply running migrations for the new `USER` model will not suffice. You will have to run migrations for the social auth as well. I did it by complete & forced migration of the entire project.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error coming from a corrupted local DB. I had to cleanup the tables: `social_auth_usersocialauth` and `django_session`.